# How to make dynamic query in anypoint studio?

Tags: anypoint-studio

If id is present in flowVars, i will fetch user from database by id. If not present, I will fetch all users. I tried to use this expression but no success:

`select * from user #[flowVars.userId != null ? 'where id = ' + flowVars.userId : '']`

error is :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''where id = 1'' at line 1 (com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException).
```

I think it creates single quote in query.

Answer (score 0):

Insert into info Values (#[payload.Cname], #[payload.orderid], #[payload.customerid], #[payload.allergies])

you can write like this a dynamic query

Comment: tell me changes what I need to do @Badda